# How to format a date to "E, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz" in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, date-format

I have a string date like this:

```
2018-08-26T00:00:00.000Z
```

Is there a way that I can format it so it looks similar to this format?

```
Fri, 24 Aug 2018 09:30:00 GMT 
E, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply construct a `Date` object, and then you can use [`Date.prototype.toUTCString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString) to format the string in the GMT format:

```js
var date = new Date('2018-08-26T00:00:00.000Z');
console.log(date.toUTCString());
```

Comment: Until ECMAScript 2018 (ed 9) *toUTCString* was implementation dependent, so older and non-conforming browsers may not return the required format.